# Ogre3D Custom Map

Tags: c++, mesh, ogre3d

I have no idea how to do this, but I need some help.  I want to make a custom 'map' for a game(buildings, ground, bridges, etc), and then load it into Ogre3D.  What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Have you read the Ogre3D documentation?

Comment: Please, also specify *in detail* your evaluation procedure for "best". Given two approaches A and B, exactly how do you decide which one is, by your critera, "best"? This is necessary to know in order to answer your question requiring the "best way".

Comment: I don't know if I should use a mesh, or something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should author it in a package like 3d Studio Max or Maya and then export it using an OGRE exporter. (For instance, OgreMax for 3d Studio Max. It's what I'm currently using on a project that I'm using OGRE with.) It exports a .mesh file, .material file(s), and potentially a .skeleton file(s) if you have animations. Then you can load it up with OGRE and render it in your application.

Edit:

And to be more specific, you can also export a .scene file as well, depending on how big your export is. Given you want buildings/ground/bridges, .scene is probably your best bet and will work well with the scene managers.

Comment: Thanks! :)  Also, I am using blender, but I believe it works the same.

Answer (score 1):

3d Studio - good choice. If have it, of course.

**Blender** - powerful opensource 3D-editor. Also work good. And it's **free**. Ogre3D export / import / other tools for Blender > http://ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Tools%3A+Blender